Are people with schizophrenia obligated in pru urvu?
It seems as though there is at least some genetic component to schizophrenia that is inherited. To prevent offspring from having schizophrenia, can someone with schizophrenia refrain from procreation?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18401/6592

Obviously a person should have a serious conversation with a competent rabbi and mental-health professional...

Even HaEzer 44 says that a shoteh cannot take part in Kiddushin. It follows that they are not obligated.

@Shimshon OP didn't ask about a shoteh.

@shmosel how is a schizophrenic not a shoteh? This article says they are: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/studies-halakha/philosophy-halakha/mental-illness-jewish-law-1

@Shimshon Shoteh is not a permanent state. When they are healthy -that us, not actively experiencing psychosis- they are not a shoteh at all. See ch. 7 of Gittin.

The way to find the answer is by consulting a psychiatrist, but unless Gittin refers explicitly to psychosis, I think you’ll need more support for that statement

See another source that schizophrenia is shoteh: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/who-is-a-shoteh/14381#14381
